# Azure SQL database table variable collation

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Azure SQL Servers have a fixed collation of SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. I have an Azure SQL database with a collation of Latin1_General_CI_AS. I seem to be getting collation conflict errors when creating a table variable and joining to a database table. Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @resultingRoles TABLE ([MemberRoleName] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @resultingRoles
SELECT DISTINCT([MemberRoleName]) FROM [RolesInRoles]
    WHERE
[ApplicationName] = @applicationName AND
[MemberRoleName]  IN (@role0,@role1,@role2)
WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT>0)
    BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO @resultingRoles
    SELECT DISTINCT([roles].[TargetRoleName])
    FROM [RolesInRoles] AS [roles] 
    INNER JOIN @resultingRoles sj ON sj.[MemberRoleName] = [roles].[MemberRoleName] 
    LEFT JOIN @resultingRoles lf on [roles].[TargetRoleName] = lf.[MemberRoleName]
    WHERE lf.[MemberRoleName] IS NULL
    AND [roles].[ApplicationName] = @applicationName
END
```

This results in the following error:

Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I presume this is because the tabel variable column MemberRoleName is being created with the SQL Server collation NOT the database collation. My expectation was that the database collation would be used - am I wrong?

Is there any way to check the collation on a table variable?

Edit: I cannot change this SQL code to explicitly set the collation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
 DECLARE @resultingRoles TABLE ([MemberRoleName] NVARCHAR(256) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
```

Comment: This is not my application code - I cannot make changes to it

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for . The table does not have a collation .. it would be the text/char columns in the table. Also table variables and temp tables are created in tempdb, so would use the server collation

Comment: You might want to have a look at this : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/working-with-collations-in-sql-azure/

Comment: I'm asking if the table variable should use the server or database collation.

Comment: The table variable as i mentioned would use the server collation, however i think a variable would be in the database collation

Answer (score 0):

You can run following query to get the informaiton you need:

```
--List the collation supported
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations();

--Get server collation    
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') AS Collation;  

--Get databse collation
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') AS Collation;

--Get Table columns collation
SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.columns
WHERE    object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableName', 'U')
AND name <> 'id'

--Update Table Column collation
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```